# SELECT 2 random records from one random column MySQL

Tags: mysql

During selecting 2 random records from random columns i get 2 records from different random columns

My table

```
id  | name1 |  name2  | name3 
------------------------------
1    user1     test1      pr1        
2    user2     test2      pr2   
3    user3     test3      pr3   
.............................
n    userN     testN      prN
```

```
SELECT CASE FLOOR(RAND()*3+1)
                     WHEN 1 THEN name1 
                     WHEN 2 THEN name2
                     WHEN 3 THEN name3
                     END AS name
            FROM names ORDER BY RAND() limit 2
```

and i get results like that:

```
|name|
----
user1
pr1
```

But i need:

```
|name|
----
user1
userN
```

or

```
|name|
----
pr2   
pr5
```

Thank you in advance for you answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT
  CASE x.r
    WHEN 1 THEN name1 
    WHEN 2 THEN name2
    WHEN 3 THEN name3
  END AS name
FROM names
CROSS JOIN (SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*3+1) as r) x
ORDER BY RAND() limit 2
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9MUuVjpSbWv3BCARwXm7Dg/0)

Since the subquery in the FROM clause (CROSS JOIN) will be evaluated only once, you get one random value between 1 and 3, instead of two different values. And this way you always get two random rows with a value from the same (random) column.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query like this:

```
SELECT CASE @COLNR
        WHEN 1 THEN name1 
        WHEN 2 THEN name2
        WHEN 3 THEN name3
    END AS name
FROM names
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @COLNR := FLOOR(RAND()*3+1) ) AS INIT
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 2;
```

or this: it will get the max ROWs

```
SELECT CASE @COLNR
        WHEN 1 THEN name1 
        WHEN 2 THEN name2
        WHEN 3 THEN name3
    END AS name
FROM names
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT FLOOR( RAND() * COUNT(*)+1) INTO @COLNR from names ) AS INIT
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: `INTO @COLNR` will not work in a subquery. But what is `COUNT(*)` good for? if you have 10 rows, you could select the 10th column (which doesn't exist)?

Comment: @ Paul Spiegel - oh oh - my mistake. you are 100% right. jhenya-d use the answer from Paul Spiegel